# Make layout aware whether keyboard is visible or not

Tags: android, android-layout, android-softkeyboard

I'm trying to make a layout aware whether the softkeyboard is visible or not since it covers part of the UI. Moving the UI up when the keyboard comes up and making it scrollable would be preferable.

Is this possible to do, and if so, how?

**Image of view without keyboard:**
[nokeyboard](http://puu.sh/jg4xL/cc4cd6d0e9.png)

**Image of view with keyboard:**
[with keyboard](http://puu.sh/jg4Dt/8ee511b379.png%20withkeyboard)

**XML**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/dialog_min_width"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/spacing_l"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:minWidth="@dimen/dialog_min_width"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/dialog_content"
            style="@style/DialogContent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/dialog_title"
                style="@style/DialogTitle"
                android:text="@string/label_start_round"
                />

            <TextView
                style="@style/InputLabel"
                android:text="@string/label_player_name"
                />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/player_name"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.EditText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textAutoCorrect"
                />

            <TextView
                style="@style/InputLabel"
                android:text="@string/label_player_handicap"
                />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/player_handicap"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.EditText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                />

            <TextView
                style="@style/InputLabel"
                android:text="@string/label_gender"
                />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner_gender"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />

            <TextView
                style="@style/InputLabel"
                android:text="@string/label_selected_tee"
                />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/player_tee"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/dialog_footer"
        style="@style/DialogFooter">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/button_cancel"
            style="@style/DialogButton"
            android:text="@string/label_cancel"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/button_start"
            style="@style/DialogButton"
            android:text="@string/label_start"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The android:windowSoftInputMode did not work for me since I was using a LinearLayout (overlapping the RelativeLayout in the background, however this wasn't show in the question). What I had to do was:

1. Change the outermost LinearLayout to a RelativeLayout
2. Put both inner LinearLayouts within the ScrollView (and make the lower LinearLayout a RelativeLayout to fix some layout issues related to the move)
3. Add `getDialog().getWindow().setSoftInputMode((WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE));` to the fragments `onCreateView`

The manifest could remain unchanged using this solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at the [android:windowSoftInputMode](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft) setting in your manifest.

> The adjustment made to the activity's main window — whether it is
>   resized smaller to make room for the soft keyboard or whether its
>   contents pan to make the current focus visible when part of the window
>   is covered by the soft keyboard.